# ListView no longer reacts to onclick after a call to setSelection()

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

In [Zwitscher](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA) I have a `ListView` that displays a number of tweets. The user can then reload the timeline and if there are new tweets, the new list is loaded into the list adapter (plus some old ones) and I scroll to the end of the list via

```
listView.setSelection(x);
```

where `x` is the number of the oldest tweets of the freshly loaded ones. This works very well.
But unfortunately this "disables" the `onItemClick()` and `onItemLongClick()` handlers on the view. If I then (e.g. from a button) call

```
listView.setSelection(0);
```

The handlers for `onItemClick()` and `onItemLongClick()` are "enabled" again.

I've verified that the handlers are still set on the listView after the call to `setSelection(x)`. And disabling that call to `setSelection(x)` also does not "disable" the handlers.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

The full source is here: https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TweetListActivity.java and the lines in question are in `onPostExecute()` on line 417

Comment: How do you update the list I hope its notifydatasetchanged? And just as a hack what if youdo sset selection to x then to 0 and then back to x does it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce that. `onItemClick()` is called after any `setSelection`. Try to isolate the problem down by creating a test case that reproduces. If you succeed, I thing you should submit a bug to android.