# Adding an onclicklistener to listview (android)

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I've managed to implement a great listview that I found here http://www.learn-android.com/2011/11/22/lots-of-lists-custom-adapter/comment-page-1/
but I can't seem to add an onclicklistener
I just want to be able to do an action when I click on the row, with the data that the row contains of course
any ideas?
thanks

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.liste);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // Setup the list view
    final ListView prestListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    final prestationAdapterEco prestationAdapterEco = new prestationAdapterEco(this, R.layout.prestation);

    prestListView.setAdapter(prestationAdapterEco);

    // Populate the list, through the adapter
    for(final prestationEco entry : getPrestations()) {
        prestationAdapterEco.add(entry);
    }
    prestListView.setClickable(true);
    prestListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            Object o = prestListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String str=(String)o;//As you are using Default String Adapter
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is failing - or how is it failing? Do you see behavior like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579754/listview-no-longer-reacts-to-onclick-after-a-call-to-setselection ?

Comment: it crashes the app when I execute it

Comment: it loads the list but crashes when I select an Item

Comment: @MikeBryant saying "It crashes" isn't very informative. Can you please post the stacktrace that is produced when the app crashes?

Comment: I don't know where that would be but I added a try catch statement and I get "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.packagename.prestationEco"

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Object o = prestListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        prestationEco str = (prestationEco)o; //As you are using Default String Adapter
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),str.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: that's exactly what I tried, how would I get the item's details?

Comment: I always add a vector into my custom listview and to get data i create a new object, eg    Object obj = (Object)Vector.get(position);

Comment: i have created a custom list adapter wherin i pass the vector to the class and it creates a listview with the total vector size and data in it...

Answer (score 9):

If your Activity extends ListActivity, you can simply override the `OnListItemClick()` method like so:

```
/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override  
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {  
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);

    // TODO : Logic
}
```

Comment: the listview just extends activity not listactivity, http://www.learn-android.com/2011/11/22/lots-of-lists-custom-adapter/comment-page-1/

Comment: For me in a ListFragment this was the ONLY way to get onClick to work. setOnItemClickListener just doesn't work. I guess the same would be true for ListActivity. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080332/listfragment-onitemclicklistener-not-working

Answer (score 1):

The prestListView.getItemAtPosition(position); returns the UI widget: Text, Icon, ...

Try this instead:

```
Object o = prestationAdapterEco.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

or

```
Object o = arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Get the object from the adapter. Not from the list-view.

2.
Object o is a prestationEco object. Not a String.

Answer (score 1):

```
list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
Object o = prestListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
String str=(String)o;//As you are using Default String Adapter
```

The `o` that you get back is not a String, but a `prestationEco` so you get a CCE when doing the `(String)o`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3)
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Please always add a comment to your answer.