# ListFragment onItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I'm using the tabbed layout (with swipe).
Here I have 3 tabs with controlled by a SectionsPagerAdapter. Each tab is a ListFragment.

Now I want to get an event fired when one of the items in the list is clicked. I would like a listener for each tab.

Here's the code now (Which isn't working, event is not fired).

```
public class NyhederFragment extends ListFragment {
     public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
     private static final String TAG="NyhederFragment";
     private List<Item> newsItems;
     private ArrayList newsHeadlines;
     private ArrayAdapter adapter;
     private BroadcastReceiver updateReciever;

public NyhederFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ListView newsList = new ListView(getActivity());
    newsList.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    newsList.setId(R.id.list);
    DatabaseHelper dbConn = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    newsItems = dbConn.getAllItemsFromNews();
    newsHeadlines = new ArrayList();
    for(Item i : newsItems){
        newsHeadlines.add(i.getTitle());
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, newsHeadlines);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    newsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
            Log.i("debug", "single click");
        }
    });

    dbConn.close();

    getActivity().registerReceiver(updateReciever, new IntentFilter("ArticlesUpdated"));
    return newsList;
}
}
```

What is it, I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you are using `ListFragment` then you can simply use its override method `onListItemClick()`

```
@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }
```

Comment: Yes. Figured that out but couldn't reply to my own question. (See comment on below post).

But thanks a lot anyway! :)

Comment: Yay! Finally something that worked! I've spent the past half an hour looking for a solution, and this was it! Thanks!

Comment: saved me ! in my case

Answer (score 15):

It is due to custom list item. The default focus is with custom list item (button/textview). It causes this issue.

Please add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in root layout of list element. 
Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

change `setListAdapter(adapter);` to `newsList.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Hmm.. Still not working. But I bet that this was an error too. Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out myself :)

The solution was to override onListItemClick from ListFragment :)

Can't answer because of to low reputation though.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to create or re-use or an existing handler that implements `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`, rather than implementing `onListItemClick()` within the `ListFragment`, you can do so by getting a reference to the `ListView` of the `ListFragment` and setting its listener. In your `ListFragment.onResume()` you could do:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Stop touching me");
        }
    });
}
```

In my case, I can use the same listener from an `Activity` with a `ListView`, a `ListActivity` or a `ListFragment`, e.g.

`listView.setOnItemClickListener(new MyListViewOnClickListener(getActivity()));`