# Yet another adding onclicklistener to listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to add a onclicklistener and uncomment [this line](https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-BluetoothScannerFinishedProject/blob/master/BluetoothScanner/app/src/main/java/com/tutsplus/matt/bluetoothscanner/DeviceListFragment.java#L124). Here is my modified code stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9097790/3990158)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_deviceitem_list, container, false);
    ToggleButton scan = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.scan);
    // Set the adapter
    mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) mListView).setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
    //mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Object listItem = mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "item is clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });  
    return view;
}
```

However, this I need to show the text of [device name and the address](https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-BluetoothScannerFinishedProject/blob/master/BluetoothScanner/app/src/main/java/com/tutsplus/matt/bluetoothscanner/DeviceListFragment.java#L97) instead of "item is clicked". Any help?

Comment: Was the answer below not what you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setText(device.getName()+":"+device.getAddress());
        toast.show();
```