# how to pass popup into my listview activity ...the listitem are coming from server ...using json android

Tags: android, json, listview, popup

how to pass popup in my submenu activity...i tried many codes but nothing is working for me ...can anybody help me as here i m getting listview item from server if i select any item it should popup a window .

here is my SubMenu Activity:

```
public class SubMenu extends AppCompatActivity{
    // Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String RANK = "id";
    static String COUNTRY = "name";

    static String FLAG = "image";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_menu);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml

        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        // @Override
        //  protected void onPreExecute() {
        //  super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        //   mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SubMenu.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        //   mProgressDialog.setTitle("Categories of Main categories.....");
        // Set progressdialog message
        //  mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        //  mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        //  mProgressDialog.show();
        // }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonarray = JsonFunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://cloud.granddubai.com/broccoli/menu_typeitem.php");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
//                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("main_menu_items");


                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                   // map.put("id", jsonobject.getString("id"));
                    map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));

                    map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(SubMenu.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to pass it. listView has items. you can use an onClick listner to your list view and get the position of the list item that got clicked. Then you can do what you want to do. Display a popup i guess

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097723/adding-an-onclicklistener-to-listview-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package applications.android.dt.myapplication;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

import askar.com.multiplerouteandroid.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String RANK = "id";
    static String COUNTRY = "name";

    static String FLAG = "image";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_menu);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // Get the view from listview_main.xml

        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        // @Override
        //  protected void onPreExecute() {
        //  super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        //   mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SubMenu.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        //   mProgressDialog.setTitle("Categories of Main categories.....");
        // Set progressdialog message
        //  mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        //  mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        //  mProgressDialog.show();
        // }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonarray = JsonFunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://cloud.granddubai.com/broccoli/menu_typeitem.php");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
//                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("main_menu_items");


                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    // map.put("id", jsonobject.getString("id"));
                    map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));

                    map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(SubMenu.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            // Close the progressdialog
            // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                    = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                    .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    popupView,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
            btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                }});

            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(view, 50, -30);
        }
    }
}
```

**R.layout.popup**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">
 <LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:layout_margin="1dp"
     android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
     >
     <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:layout_margin="20dp">
      <TextView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="It's a PopupWindow" />
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
      <Button
          android:id="@+id/dismiss"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Dismiss" />
      </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u help me through coding..as i   m newbie here

Comment: i have added SubMenu activity ..in this activity where to put popup code ?

Comment: but this is dialog

Comment: what else you want? popup means what you meant?.please mention your proper requirment

Comment: pop window is different from dialog box rite?

Comment: i m trying to add this on ur code but it gives me error..can u add this in my code n send me back plz

Comment: i m trying to add this on my code but it gives me error..can u add this in my code n send me back plz

Comment: hey me also from dubai

Comment: can i have cross mark symbol instead of dismiss button

Comment: no like we usally see on popwindow right side on top

Comment: corner side...and how can i make this window bigger and in center??

Comment: Use Alert Builder or Dialog. if the popup has more data then use dialog fragment.