# is it possible to set onClickListener for custom listView item in activity?

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

Is it possible to bind onClickListener for listView item buttons in activity? My listView item has name, delete and edit buttons. listView items are stored in List.

exercises_list_view_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteExerciseBtn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/editExerciseBtn"
        android:layout_width="26dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/deleteExerciseBtn"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_btn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/exerciseName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/editExerciseBtn"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="This is a Large text with fill width"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

code in activity :

```
@Override
public void onButtonClickListner(int position, String value) {
    Toast.makeText(create_workout.this, "Button click " + value,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

List<WorkoutExercise> workoutExercises = workout.getWorkoutExercises();
ListView exercisesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exerciseListView);
WorkoutExerciseListAdapter listAdapter = new WorkoutExerciseListAdapter(this, R.layout.exercises_list_view_item, workoutExercises);
listAdapter.setCustomButtonListener(create_workout.this);
exercisesList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Since WorkoutExerciseListAdapted has a lot of code I pasted it here : https://pastebin.com/FYNVVQnS

What I am trying to do is :
If user clicks edit button I need to pass Exercise object to another activity for editing.
If user clicks delete button I need to remove that item from List<> and update listView (with notifyDataSetChanged() ? )

I tried to look for answer through stackoverflow and google, but it either didn't work or my app started crashing. 
Few of tried examples:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9e8439/create-custom-listener-on-button-in-listitem-listview-in-a/
[Adding an onclicklistener to listview (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097723/adding-an-onclicklistener-to-listview-android)
and others..

I would appreciate any advice. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Update your `customButtonListener` interface as below:

```
public interface customButtonListener {
    public void onEditButtonClickListner(int position, String value);
    public void onDeleteButtonClickListner(int position);
}
```

**2.** In adapters `getView()` method set click listener to `edit` and `delete` buttons:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {

    ............
    ...................

    // Edit
    viewHolder.editBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (customListner != null) {
                customListner.onEditButtonClickListner(position, getItem(position).getExerciseName());
            }
        }
    });

    // Delete
    viewHolder.deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (customListner != null) {
                customListner.onDeleteButtonClickListner(position);
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

**3.** In your activity, add `CustomButtonListener` to your `ListView`:

```
A. Get item position from `onEditButtonClickListner()` and get `workoutExercise` object and pass it to another activity 
B. Get item position from `onDeleteButtonClickListner()` and delete item and upadte ListView.
```

**Add below codes in your Activity:**

```
    ..........
    .................

    listAdapter.setCustomButtonListener(create_workout.this);
    exercisesList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    exercisesList.setCustomButtonListener(new WorkoutExerciseListAdapter.customButtonListener() {

        @Override
        public void onEditButtonClickListner(int position, String value) 
        {
            // Item
            WorkoutExercise workoutExercise = workoutExercises.get(position);

            // Do something with object workoutExercise 
        }

        @Override
        public void onDeleteButtonClickListner(int position) 
        {
            // Delete
            workoutExercises.remove(position);

            // Update ListView
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thank you for your help. I combined both of your examples and everything is working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to **fire any events for every list-item on your list-view**, Then you should implement it in your **BaseAdapter** class. 
On your **WorkoutExerciseListAdapter**, Inside the **getView**() methord define your event listner.

If you need to get the click event on your **Activity**, Then implement and use an **interface**, If so then at the WorkoutExerciseListAdapter

```
MyNotifier listner;

public interface MyNotifier
{
  void OnButtonClicked;
}

public void setMyNotificationListner(MyNotifier listner)
{
  this.listner=listner;
}
```

Then when the button clicks

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
     Button b=(Button)v.getViewByID(<id>);
     b.setOnClickListner(new OnClickListner...
     {
       listner.OnButtonClicked()
     }
    }
```

At the MainActivity

```
WorkoutExerciseListAdapter listAdapter = new WorkoutExerciseListAdapter(this, R.layout.exercises_list_view_item, workoutExercises);
listAdapter.setMyNotificationListner(new MyNotifier {..//You get click calls here..};)
```